# file (pdf ) download using React and parcel bundler

Tags: reactjs, web

I have a piece of code that is supposed to download a local file(which is at the same file level) when a button is clicked. Instead it downloads an `index.html` file, which has nothing.
This happens when I am running locally and test using chrome, edge. It downloads the index.html file.

Now when I use code sandbox to test it, it downloads the correct pdf file.
Can anyone explain what is the issue here.

I am using mui for style and parcel bundler.
Could someone point out what wrong I am doing here?

Here is the link for code sand box:

https://codesandbox.io/s/file-downloader-6q9rgh

The same code when I run locally in my vs code and test in chrome downloads a html file.

To view the code here is the link:

[code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/file-downloader-6q9rgh)

Thank you

while testing locally in chrome, edge, It should download the pdf file instead of html file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I was using Typescript and needed to do the following:

1. Add a global typescript declaration file, `[filename].d.ts`, in the `src` directory and insert:

```
declare module '*.pdf';
```

2. And also add a `.parcelrc` file in the project root folder, then add this to it:

```
{
    "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
    "transformers": {
        "*.pdf": ["@parcel/transformer-raw"]
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.